# Spring Boot application with ftp

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I need help ,i had tested Spring Boot app with spring-integration-ftp and it works if i use it in main class  SpringBootFtpApplication
It runs and copy file from remote server to my local place but it works automatically .

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootFtpApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootFtpApplication.class, args);
    }

     @Bean
        public SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpSessionFactory() {
            DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
            sf.setHost("123.ftpserver.com");
            sf.setPort(21);
            sf.setUsername("demo");
            sf.setPassword("xxxxx");
            return new CachingSessionFactory<FTPFile>(sf);
        }

    @Bean
    public FtpInboundFileSynchronizer ftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(ftpSessionFactory());
        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory("upload");
        fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.txt"));
        return fileSynchronizer;
    }
    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {

        PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
        pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(10));
        return pollerMetadata;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "ftpChannel")
    public MessageSource<File> ftpMessageSource() {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source =
                new FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(ftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File("ftp-inbound"));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
        return source;
    }


    @Bean
     @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpChannel")
     public MessageHandler handler() {
         return new MessageHandler() {


             @Override
             public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                 Object payload = message.getPayload();
                 if(payload instanceof File){
                     File f = (File) payload;
                     System.out.println(f.getName());
                 }else{
                     System.out.println(message.getPayload());
                 }
             }

         };
     }
}
```

How to make this code copy to another class and then manually started from another controller class for example

```
public class ImportFromFtpServer(){
 /*
@Bean 
public SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpSessionFactory() ...
@Bean
public FtpInboundFileSynchronizer ftpInboundFileSynchronizer() ...
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "ftpChannel")
public MessageSource<File> ftpMessageSource() ...
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handler()...
*/
}

    @Controller
public class MyController(){
   public class startFtpTransfer(){
       ImportFromFtpServer() imp = new ImportFromFtpServer();
      //how to call metod for ftp transfer ? 
 }
}
```

I try to put all code in one class and put @Configuration annotation but then this execution run automatically and i don't have any control over execution , but i want to have control when this transfer need to start

Any tip or help will be appreciate. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to fetch files on demand, consider using an outbound gateway (`get` command) instead (or directly using an `FtpRemoteFileTemplate`).

Creating a polled flow for a single file is not really appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The `@InboundChannelAdapter` has:

```
/*
 {@code SmartLifecycle} options.
 Can be specified as 'property placeholder', e.g. {@code ${foo.autoStartup}}.
 */
String autoStartup() default "true";
```

Which you can configure to `false`. Lately when you really need the work from that you should `start()` it because `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` is `Lifecycle` implementation.

What you need is to inject that bean:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("springBootFtpApplication.ftpMessageSource.inboundChannelAdapter")
Lifecycle ftpChannelAdapter;
```

**UPDATE**

Since `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`s are for the `@InboundChannelAdapter` annotations are created a bit later, there are not feasible for the `@Autowired` phase. What you need in your application is manually performing dependency injection. Something like this:

```
@Autowired
private BeanFactory beanFactory;

@GetMapping("/startFtpPolling")
public void startFtpSource() {
    this.beanFactory.getBean("demoApplication.ftpMessageSource.inboundChannelAdapter", Lifecycle.class).start();
}
```

Comment: i used only part of your solution but other half didnt work well so i put another answer so please if you can help with this

Answer (score 0):

@artem-bilan tnx for fast reply
I implemented part of your solution and put this part of code as you suggest for autoStartup and this work

```
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "ftpChannel",autoStartup = "false")
public MessageSource<File> ftpMessageSource() {...}
```

This code stopped execute automatically FTP transfer.
But after i implement second part of your solution as in this code

```
public class FtpLifecycle implements Lifecycle{

@Autowired
@Qualifier("springBootBatchTestApplication.ftpMessageSource.inboundChannelAdapter")
 Lifecycle ftpChannelAdapter;

@Override
public boolean isRunning() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void start() {
    System.out.println("Started...");
    ftpChannelAdapter.start();

}

@Override
public void stop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

and then call this method

```
ftpChannelAdapter.start();
```

in my controller class i got error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.company.ftp.FtpLifecycle.start(FtpLifecycle.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
```

I think it has to be problem with @Qualifier maybe he didn't find inboundChannelAdapter at all ? Any suggestion how to resolve this?

EDIT ON 23.6

```
public class FtpLifecycle implements Lifecycle{

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FtpLifecycle.class);

@Autowired
    @Qualifier("SpringBootBatchTestApplication.ftpMessageSource.inboundChannelAdapter")
    Lifecycle ftpChannelAdapter;


@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;

@Override
public boolean isRunning() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void start() {
    System.out.println("Started...");
    SourcePollingChannelAdapter sp = findTestCaseBean(appContext);
    ftpChannelAdapter.start();


}

@Override
public void stop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public static SourcePollingChannelAdapter findTestCaseBean(ApplicationContext appCtx) throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException {


    Map<String, SourcePollingChannelAdapter> testcases = (Map<String, SourcePollingChannelAdapter>) appCtx.getBeansOfType(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.class);
    if (testcases.isEmpty()) {
        LOGGER.warn("No classes!");
        throw new NoSuchBeanDefinitionException(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.class);
    } else {
        LOGGER.warn("There is classes!");
        SourcePollingChannelAdapter retVal = testcases.values().iterator().next();
        if (null == retVal) {
            throw new NoSuchBeanDefinitionException(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.class);
        } else {
            return retVal;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the question content your `ftpMessageSource` is declared in the `SpringBootFtpApplication`, but not `springBootBatchTestApplication` as you show in this `@Qualifier`

Comment: Sorry for that i forgot to said that i renamed my application to SpringBootBatchTestApplication, so i think this is not problem . So name of my main class is public class SpringBootBatchTestApplication

Comment: OK. Can you debug what names returns the code `this.applicationContext.getBeansOfType(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.class)` ?

Comment: Sorry but where i need to put this part of code in which class FtpLifecycle or in SpringBootBatchTestApplication? I send you code in answer to see and this code does not show anything new just same error 2017-06-23 08:36:47.831 ERROR 10904 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: null